# difference between tabHost setOnTabChangedListener and setOnTabClickListener

Tags: android

friend's
    I wanna need to know the difference between tabhost setOnTabChangedListener and OnTabClickListener
in what cases,these both are fired,is't both are same or different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same event because:

- OnTabChangedListener is fired when the tab is chenged, whatever is the cause, by a touch or by a key or by the trackball
- OnTabClickListener is fired when the tab is gonna be changed by a click